# Meaning of "No spatial index exists for join layer" when doing spatial join in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, overlapping-features

I am doing a spatial join by location.

My input layer is a shp file. It is a grid cell of the African of 0.5 x 0.5 degree latitude. It contains, a gid number which identifies the cell, the longitude and the latitude of the middle of the cell.

My join layer is a CSV file. It has different violent events which their corresponding latitude and longitude.

I am doing a spatial location by attributes using intersect option. However, when I do it, the following appears:

> No spatial index exists for join layer, performance will be severely degraded

Do you know what can be happening?

Comment: That should be the warning that the join will take some more time due to one layer not having a spatial index. Unless you have very large data sets this can be ignored.

Comment: But both files has a spatial index, right? My csv file contains 233.662 observations. It's very big,

Comment: I dont know if a csv can have an index. Convert it to geopackage and use the tool "Create spatial index". It will probably make the join alot faster

Comment: Do you mean that I should convert my csv file in a shp file using tool "Create spatial index"? Sorry but I am very new using QGIS.

Comment: Did you try to load the csv file as a vector layer and then try to create a spatial index?

Comment: Is it a problem when you run join layer **without** a spatial index? If not, just run it like that. Otherwise, do what other comments adviced: load csv and export/save it as Geopackage file, than create spatial index on that Geopackage + your shapefile.

Comment: My original dataset was a dta dataset (to use in Stata) and then I transform into csv file in order to use in QGIS. Is it any change anything? ; With respect to @Babel comment, I am not sure if I am doing with or without a spatial index. I am jus doing what I wrote in the main comment.

Comment: OK: when you just do it: what happens? Does any problem arise?

Comment: When I do what I am doing? The problem is that while the spatial join is working that message appears, so I am not sure if the result is ok or not. I think I will try the option of making my csv file in shp. To do that, I have to load as a vector layer and after create a spatial index using "Create spatial index", is what I am saying correct?

Comment: By the way, I am not sure if I am able to transform the csv and create a spatial index. It has a lot of variables and 233000 observations.

Comment: It says `**performance** is degraded` without spatial index - but not the result. Spatial indices simply speed up processing, it does not influence the (quality of the) output. So the result should be OK, it simply takes more time without spatial index.

Comment: Thank you, Babel. You are right, it is taking a lot of time and at some moment my computer is collapsing and the process do not finised. Do you know what I can do?

Comment: Save you layers as Geopackage files and create a spatial index for all of them: right click layer / Properties / Source / Create spatial index